# Problem with grouping with multiple columns?

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
public List<IncomeChannelCategoryMap> allIncomeChannels(final List<String> list) {
    final CriteriaQuery<IncomeChannelCategoryMap> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(IncomeChannelCategoryMap.class);
    final Root<IncomeChannelMapEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(IncomeChannelMapEntity.class);

    final List<Selection<?>> selections = new ArrayList<>();
    selections.add(root.get(IncomeChannelMapEntity_.incomeChannel).get(IncomeChannelEntity_.code));
    selections.add(root.get(IncomeChannelMapEntity_.logicalUnitCode));
    selections.add(root.get(IncomeChannelMapEntity_.logicalUnitIdent));
    selections.add(root.get(IncomeChannelMapEntity_.keyword));
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(selections);
    Predicate codePredicate = root.get(IncomeChannelMapEntity_.incomeChannel).get(IncomeChannelEntity_.code).in(list);
    criteriaQuery.where(codePredicate);
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

}
```

And this:

```
   @Override
    public List<IncomeChannelCategoryMap> allIncomeChannels(final EntityRequest<IncomeChannel> request) throws ApiException {
        List<String> lists = request.getEntity().getIncomeChannels();
        List<IncomeChannelCategoryMap> channels = incomeChannelMapDAO.allIncomeChannels(lists);
        return new ArrayList<>(channels.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IncomeChannelCategoryMap::getIncomeChannelCode,
                Function.identity(), (final IncomeChannelCategoryMap i1, final IncomeChannelCategoryMap i2) -> {
                    i1.setLogicalUnitIdent(i1.getLogicalUnitIdent() + "," + i2.getLogicalUnitIdent());
                    return i1;
                })).values());

    }
```

I am able to achieve this:

```
  {
    "incomeChannelCode": "DIRECT_SALES",
    "logicalUnitCode": "R_CATEGORY",
    "logicalUnitIdent": "7,8"
  }
```

from

```
[
{
    "incomeChannelCode": "DIRECT_SALES",
    "logicalUnitCode": "R_CATEGORY",
    "logicalUnitIdent": "7"
  },
  {
    "incomeChannelCode": "DIRECT_SALES",
    "logicalUnitCode": "R_CATEGORY",
    "logicalUnitIdent": "8"
  }
]
```

And everything is great but have one problem:

For example DIRECT_SALES can have another logicalUnitCode so right now im getting only one, and i want to achive for logicalUnitCode like i did for logicalUnitIdent.

Any suggestion? 
So what I want to achieve is this:

```
      {
        "incomeChannelCode": "DIRECT_SALES",
        "logicalUnitCode": "R_CATEGORY","R_TYPE",
        "logicalUnitIdent": "7,8"
      }
```

Comment: Hi None. From where did that `R_TYPE` came from? I can't see it in the original output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your updated code:

```
@Override
public List<IncomeChannelCategoryMap> allIncomeChannels(final EntityRequest<IncomeChannel> request) throws ApiException {
    List<String> lists = request.getEntity().getIncomeChannels();
    List<IncomeChannelCategoryMap> channels = incomeChannelMapDAO.allIncomeChannels(lists);
    return new ArrayList<>(channels.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IncomeChannelCategoryMap::getIncomeChannelCode,
            Function.identity(), (i1, i2) -> {
                i1.setLogicalUnitIdent(i1.getLogicalUnitIdent() + ", " + i2.getLogicalUnitIdent());
                if (!i1.getLogicalUnitCode().contains(i2.getLogicalUnitCode())) {
                    i1.setLogicalUnitCode(i1.getLogicalUnitCode() + ", " + i2.getLogicalUnitCode());
                }
                return i1;
            })).values());
}
```

Just like `logicalUnitIdent` now `logicalUnitCode` will also be grouped. Here I'm assuming that you don't want duplicates here. By duplicates I mean if `logicalUnitCode` is `"R_CATEGORY"` for both the results then you want it once as output. And if one is `"R_CATEGORY"` and the other one is `"R_TYPE"` then you want them to be grouped as `"R_CATEGORY, R_TYPE"` as output. If my assumption is correct then this is your required answer.